How can use statically typed check a dataclass create with make_dataclass
When i create and use a dataclass the "normal way" I can run and type check my code mypy without problem.
For instance, this code works perfectly fine:
@dataclass
class Person2:
    name : str
    age : int
    height : float

def f2(p : Person2):
    print(p)

But if I try to craete a dataclass with make_dataclass, I have a problem.
For instance:
types_list = [('name', str), ('age', int), ('height', float)]


Person = make_dataclass('Person', types_list)
a=Person(name="n",age=2, height=4.3)

def f(p : Person):
    print(p)


q.py:10: error: Variable "q.Person" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]

Why does this problem occurs and is it possible to fix it

Information about Person can be gleaned from a static construct like a class statement, but not from a particular call to a function about which we only know the names and types of its own arguments, not the values of those arguments.
Types constructed from values (rather than just other types) are known as dependent types, and Python's type-checking does not currently support dependent typing.

ok just to be sure. Does it mean this is impossible

As far as I know, yes. (Theoretically, a type checker could be modified to special-case the name make_dataclass and treat it much like a class statement. But that would only work when the arguments are essentially literals; you might still have arguments passed to the function that require essentially simulating the code to find out what dataclass is actually defined.)
